# Android Studio 2.2 link opencv static libraries

Tags: c++, opencv, static-libraries, android-studio-2.2

I'm trying to link the opencv native libs in Android Studio 2.2. All the topics I find about this are using Android.mk files or other methods in build.gradle file that Android Studio can't find.

I'm using Android Studio 2.2 and created the project by making a new project with c++ support.

So far I succeeded in including the OpenCV libraries in a c++ source file:

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <string>
#include "opencv.hpp"

extern "C"
jstring
Java_com_rvstudios_roomscanner_capp_MainActivity_stringFromJNI(
        JNIEnv *env,
        jobject /* this */) {
    std::string hello = "Hello from C++";

    cv::Mat image;
    cv::cvtColor(image, image, CV_BGR2GRAY);

    return env->NewStringUTF(hello.c_str());
}
```

When I try to build this I get the undefined reference error on the opencv functions which is because the static libraries (.a files) have to be linked. From what I already read this should be done in the build.gradle file.

This is my build.gradle file so far:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

def targetPlatform = "mips"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.rvstudios.roomscanner.capp"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        externalNativeBuild {
            cmake {
                cppFlags ""
                cppFlags.add("-isystem${project.rootDir}/app/src/main/cpp/vision".toString())
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = ["${project.rootDir}/app/src/main/jniLibs/${targetPlatform.toString()}/"]
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I am stuck here because I dont know how to link the static libraries. I have already seen loads of SO topics about the same problem but everything I read are using different project setups and I'm new to Android developing so I have no knowledge about it at all.

EDIT1:
My CMakeLists.txt:

```
 # Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native
# library. You should either keep the default value or only pass a
# value of 3.4.0 or lower.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds it for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             native-lib

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             # Associated headers in the same location as their source
             # file are automatically included.
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             src/main/cpp/vision/opencv.hpp )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because system libraries are included in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library( # Sets the name of the path variable.
              log-lib

              # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
              # you want CMake to locate.
              log )

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in the
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( # Specifies the target library.
                       native-lib

                       # Links the target library to the log library
                       # included in the NDK.
                       ${log-lib}

                        )
```

Comment: Did you add 'opencv.hpp' as a library to CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Yes i did! I added my CMakeLists.txt to the question field!

Comment: Try to include the 'opencv.hpp' file as follows ; #include "vision/opencv.hpp"

Comment: Doesn't work, I get the error "cannot find source file" vision/opencv.hpp

Answer (score 0):

To the CMakeLists.txt, add:

```
set(pathToOpenCV /Users/admin/Projects/OpenCV-android-sdk/sdk/native/) // Replace with your OpenCV SDK path
include_directories(${pathToOpenCV}/jni/include)
```